# Is there a way to choose the party size/type you want to join in a public game?

Tags: diablo-iii

When joining a public game, is there any option to choose details of the party you want to join such as party size? Ideally I'd also like to also be able to only join games where my class is not yet represented, and where the game is fairly full. What options are available when searching for a public game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to customize your public game search any further right now.